# Custom ViewGroup by inflating xml

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am trying to creating a custom view extends `RelativeLayout`.
To avoid adding view by coding. I prepare a xml with my custom relativelayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

So in my custom view class, I would inflate the xml by

```
View.inflate(context, R.layout.custom_view, this);
```

My question is as my class is already a `RelativeLayout`, if I doing so, I would have two levels of `RelativeLayout`. Of course, I can solve it by removing the outer `RelativeLayout` in xml. But if I am doing so, I cannot see preview in xml editor in eclipse which is the reason I want my custom view inflate from xml.

Even my custom view class extends `FrameLayout`, there would be one layer more in the view hierachy. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

To reduce the unnecessary extra layer, you need to use merge tags. Here is a good example on how to use it.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    ...
</merge>
```

Comment: But replacing RelativeLayout by merge in xml would made eclipse fail to preview as I use some relativelayout property in the child view